# Why "npm ci" removes node_modules / all packages?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, node-modules, npm-ci

Why `npm ci` [removes](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci) the `node_modules` / all packages?

> If a `node_modules` is already present, it will be automatically removed
> before `npm ci` begins its install.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you are always in the correct state, even if you, or someone else (meaning, some other tool or such), somehow fiddled with `node_modules`.

It tries to get to a state as if you just installed the module from zero.

Comment: Why not just reload the packages that do not match the version from the `package-lock.json` file?

Comment: npm doesn't know if some file hasn't been manually changed somehow.

Comment: I would assume in most cases it is enough to check the package version to know if the package needs to be reloaded.